# How do I store the following code div (navcnt) inside a href URL into array object using only Javascript

Tags: javascript

Actually, I have the following code in my page. I have the DIV id for (navcnt). I need all anchor tag URLs to store one array object using Javascript only.

I used `var x=document.getElementById("navcnt")` but how do I get the URLs from x variable.

```
<div id="navcnt">
<table id="nav" style="border-collapse:collapse;text-align:left;margin:30px auto 30px">
<tbody>
<tr valign="top">
<td class="b navend">
<a id="pnprev" class="pn" style="text-decoration:none"   href="/search?q=spring+mvc+login+example&ei=ydgFU9n8HYulrQfXhoDADg&start=40&sa=N&biw=1366&bih=363">
</td>
<td>
<a class="fl" href="/search?q=spring+mvc+login+example&ei=ydgFU9n8HYulrQfXhoDADg&start=0&sa=N&biw=1366&bih=363">
<span class="csb gbil ch" style="background:url(/images/nav_logo170_hr.png) no-repeat;background-position:-74px 0;background-size:167px;width:20px"></span>1
</a>
</td>
<td>
<a class="fl" href="/search?q=spring+mvc+login+example&ei=ydgFU9n8HYulrQfXhoDADg&start=10&sa=N">
 <span class="csb gbil ch" style="background:url(/images/nav_logo170_hr.png)      no-repeat;background-position:-74px 0;background-size:167px;width:20px"></span>
 2
</a>
</td>
<td>
<a class="fl" href="/search?q=spring+mvc+login+example&ei=ydgFU9n8HYulrQfXhoDADg&start=20&sa=N"><span class="csb gbil ch" style="background:url(/images/nav_logo170_hr.png) no-repeat;background-position:-74px 0;background-size:167px;width:20px"></span>
 3</a>
</td>
<td>
<a class="fl" href="/search?q=spring+mvc+login+example&ei=ydgFU9n8HYulrQfXhoDADg&start=30&sa=N"><span class="csb gbil ch" style="background:url(/images/nav_logo170_hr.png)no-repeat;background-position:-74px 0;background-size:167px;width:20px"></span>
4
</a>
</td>
<td>
 <a class="fl" href="/search?q=spring+mvc+login+example&ei=ydgFU9n8HYulrQfXhoDADg&start=40&sa=N"><span class="csb gbil ch" style="background:url(/images/nav_logo170_hr.png) no-repeat;background-position:-74px 0;background-size:167px;width:20px"></span>
 5
 </a>
 </td>
 </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using just JavaScript you should be able to do it as following:

```
var list, href, i;
var urlsList = new Array();
list = document.getElementById('navcnt').getElementsByTagName('a');
for(i=0;i<list.length;i++) {
    urlsList.push(list[i].href);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQuery to do that by first getting your navcnt div :

```
var navcnt = $('navcnt');
```

Then you can for example parse all the anchor in the preceding variable
and store all the URLs in an array :

```
var urlsList = new Array();
$('a', navcnt).each(function(){
    urlsList.push(this.attr('href'));
});
```

Comment: First i say thank you for answering. i need only javascript logic